# 802.11 packet capture using NDIS

Tags: sniffer, ndis, wifi

Is it possible to capture 802.11 frames in managed mode using windows NDIS filter driver?

If not, is there any other way to capture managment frames (auth/deauth/beacon) in managed mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) to control and capture packet in a network.

EDIT: [This software](https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/wlan-software/wlan-scanner-acrylic-wifi-free/) may help you to capture packets if you are using Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately WinPcap (used in wireshark) does not support capturing 802.11 frames.

Comment: Which frames are you investing to capture? I used Wireshark to capture beacon frames of standard 802.11.

Comment: I'm interested in analysing and rejecting beacon/auth/deauth managment frames. IIf I'm correct, Acrylic uses monitor mode for capturing the packets which will dissalow me to send packets normally (my guess).

Comment: Yes right. If you are using your pc in monitor mode to capture beacon and exchange of packets you can't use at the same time the same network interface you should have another device set as normal mode and connected at the same network.

Comment: The Acrylic WiFi free version is just a scanner right? I haven't tried the professional version of it, but looks like the free version cannot do much except for scanning. It (free version) has some fairly good UI, but I don't see how it can do the capture without even the Monitor button.

Comment: As it's reported in [here](https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/wlan-software/wifi-analyzer-acrylic-professional/wifi-network-capture-monitor-mode-windows/) with the free version you can't switch to capture mode. [Here](https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/blog/how-to-capture-wifi-traffic-using-wireshark-on-windows/) you can find a tutorial to capture traffic for the pro version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture all the 802.11 frames, then you need to put the NIC into Monitor Mode.  However, the standard Windows driver model does not allow the NIC to transmit or receive any packets while in Monitor Mode; the NIC is strictly passive.  So there's no software that can capture all frames while also initiating an 802.11 authentication over the same NIC simultaneously.

Third party products that integrate their software with a custom driver for specific hardware may circumvent the above limitation.  This tight integration allows the product to do things the normal driver API wouldn't allow.

That being said, I've always found it cheaper and easier to just get a second wireless NIC.  You can put one NIC into monitor mode (e.g., with [Message Analyzer](http://blogs.technet.com/b/messageanalyzer/) or netmon), and use the other to generate traffic.  Both NICs can be plugged into the same PC or different PCs.